# On swiper.js, add stop, play button

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

On swiper.js, I try to add play, stop button on auto slider.
So I tried like this

```
$(function() {
     var homeSwiper = new Swiper('.home_top_swiper', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev', 
        paginationClickable: true,
        autoplay: 3000,
        autoplayDisableOnInteraction: true,
        loop: true,
        autoHeight: true
    });

    $(".swiper-button-pause").click(function(){
                Swiper.autoplay.stop();
            });

            $(".swiper-button-play").click(function(){
                Swiper.autoplay.play();
            });
});

<div class="home_top_swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper"> 
        <div class="swiper-slide">11 </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">22 </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">33 </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-button-prev">prev</div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next">next</div>

    <div class="swiper-button-play">play</div>
    <div class="swiper-button-pause">stop</div>

</div>
```

But stop,play button is not work for me.
What did I missed it? Anyone know?
Please help.

Comment: could you solve it yet ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the variable you assigned swiper to.

```
var homeSwiper = new Swiper('.home_top_swiper', {
  // …

  $(".swiper-button-pause").click(function(){
    homeSwiper.autoplay.stop();
  });

  $(".swiper-button-play").click(function(){
    homeSwiper.autoplay.start();
  });
}
```